# print data per day, week, month, year

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have data in below format.

```
iPAddress   + timeVisited
=========================
 varchar    +  timestamp
```

What I wanted to fetch is

1. Report that have total IP per day (system date)
2. Report that have total IP per week (if today is tue, I need this week and not last 7 days)
3. Report that have total IP per month (current month... if today is 18 then from 1-18 of this month)
4. Report that have total IP per year

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: "Get data" is not that clear... What do you need ? A count of different ip address by 1. 2. 3. 4 ?`something else ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus : I need total visited counter per day, per week, per month, per year...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is what I used

### Current date

```
select count(*) from myTable where DATE(myTime) = DATE(NOW());
```

### Current week

```
select count(*) from myTable where YEAR(myTime) = YEAR(NOW()) AND WEEKOFYEAR(myTime) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

### Current month

```
select count(*) from myTable where YEAR(myTime) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(myTime) = MONTH(NOW());
```

### Current year

```
select count(*) from myTable where YEAR(myTime) = YEAR(NOW());
```

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6e1e/2)

### Note:

`YEAR(myTime) = YEAR(NOW())` in current week and current month plays very important role.

Think of date as `2012-10-30` and `2013-10-30`.

Comment: Well, and you get what you want, or not ?

Answer (score 1):

To get all  the records for today

```
select iPAddress from table_name where date(timeVisited) = curdate();
```

To get all the records of current week

```
select iPAddress from table_name where week(timeVisited) = week(curdate()) and year(timeVisited) = year(curdate());
```

To get all the records for current month

```
select iPAddress from table_name where month(timeVisited) = month(curdate()) and year(timeVisited) = year(curdate());
```

And to get all the records of current year

```
select iPAddress from table_name where year(timeVisited) = year(curdate());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry to say, but this will give incorrect data (week and month)... 21-10-2012 and 21-10-2011 have same week number but wrong year... so current year week count is wrong...

Comment: what prevents you to modify the source a little and add a year check? Like 

"select iPAddress from table_name where week(timeVisited) = week(curdate()) and year(timeVisited) = year(curdate());"



I gave you the clue. It's not tough to understand what do you need to do from there. Same goes about the month!